# Google Oauth request results in invalid grant error

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-ads-api, google-api-php-client

We have an app with offline access_type token. Yesterday all queries were broken, because authorization failed

```
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
```

resulted in a

> `400 Bad Request` response: { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad Request" }).

We use SDK [Google Ads API Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-php) for any queries to API.

Code example:

```
// Generate a refreshable OAuth2 credential for authentication.
        $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())->fromFile($filePathName)->build();
        $loggerFactory    = new LoggerFactory();
        $logger           = $loggerFactory->createLogger('TestChannel',
            APPLICATION_DIRECTORY . ".log/google/adsapi.date("Y-m").".log",
            'DEBUG');

        // Construct a Google Ads client configured from a properties file and the
        // OAuth2 credentials above.
        $googleAdsClient = (new GoogleAdsClientBuilder())
            ->fromFile(std::lpath($filePathName))
            ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
            ->withLogger($logger)
            ->build();
        $query = "SELECT customer_client.status FROM customer_client";
        $googleAdsServiceClient = $googleAdsClient->getGoogleAdsServiceClient();
        $response               = $googleAdsServiceClient->search(
            $customerId,
            $query,
            ['pageSize' => self::PAGE_SIZE]
        );
        return $response->getIterator()->current();
```

App is in production in google cloud console.

What have we already done:

- changed password for account
- reset secret and generate new refresh token

Create new app isn't good solution for us, because I think, we couldn't quickly increase limits to API (but in this moment we were forced to use an app with basic limits and quota)

Any idea how to solve this problem or how contact Google oAuth team with this question?

Related to https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/nvLa0xPkdUs/m/0P3LcxBgAQAJ

**Update: I had found, that there is no link to my app in https://myaccount.google.com/permissions
Anyone know, how to add this permissions again?**

[image: How permissions must be linked]

Comment: And authorizing the user again didnt fix it? Is your app in testing or production in google cloud console?  Please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Support of Google Ads forwarded me to ask in stackoverflow. Problem is in authentication, that's why they can't help me. But I can reproduce the problem only with one single app, another apps work fine. Of course, I can't share credentials in public. I mean, I need to find path to support of google oAuth.

Comment: @DaImTo No, didn't fix. Support of Google Ads forwarded me to ask in stackoverflow. Problem is in authentication, that's why they can't help me. But I can reproduce the problem only with one single app, another apps work fine. Of course, I can't share credentials in public. I mean, I need to find path to support of google oAuth. If you want any code example,  I can suggest any of this https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-php/tree/main/examples

Comment: Single project in google cloud console? or same project two different sets of credentials files?

Comment: @DaImTo single project in google cloud console. I mean, I found the problem, updated question, but still try find solution

Comment: Those update link you posted is where google displays third party applications your account has authorized to access your data.

Comment: Yes and problem was, that there wasn't granted permissions after enabling access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is going to be a wild guess. The issue being that invalid_grant can have a lot of possible causes.

One of them is trying to use a refresh token with a different client id and client secret then the one that was used to create it.

In comments you mentioned that you created another credentials file. And one file works the other doesn't.  This may be due to the fact that you a have a refresh token stored and you are trying to refresh the access token using the refresh token from a credentials file that was not used to create it.

solution, delete your stored refresh token,  pick the credentials file you want to use.  Your application should request consent of the user again. All should then work.

Again wild guess Let me know if what happens.

Comment: Thank you for participating, I solved my problem with manipulating with callback URL (and creating web app credentials against desktop). When my callback script received data, google granted necessary permission to my account.